# How to pass data from the third screen to first screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

In my app, the first screen navigates to the second screen through `Navigator.of(context).push`. Then the second screen navigates to the third screen through `Navigator.pushReplacement`. When I `pop` on the third screen, the app will back to the first screen, skipping the second screen.

If I want to pass data back from the second screen to the first screen, I can simply use `await Navigator.push(context)` on my first screen, then when I `pop` on the second screen, I can pass in the data in context. However, in this case, which involves 3 screens, I can't use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've pushed a flutter project solving your issue using the bloc pattern for state management. 
The app has 3 pages. 
The first and second have only simple labels wrapped in tap gesture(navigation).
On the third is the input that changes the value of the labels on page one and two.
[git repo](https://github.com/gidgol/flutter-bloc-state-mng)

This the official documentation regarding flutter state management [flutter state management](http://%20https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options)

Answer (score 1):

Use Navigator.of(context).push to go second screen to Third screen, and when you pop the third screen your code which is present in .then in seond screen will pop the second screen and pass the data of second screen to first screen.

first screen to second:-

```
Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(
   builder: (context)=>SecondScreen()
   )).then((value){  //value is the data which you pass while poping the second screen

});
```

second screen to third:-

```
Navigator.push(context, CupertinoPageRoute(
   builder: (context)=>ThirdScreen()
   )).then((value){ 
  Navigator.pop(context,your data)
 });
```

Comment: For some reason, I need to use `Navigator.pushReplacement` from second screen to third screen

Comment: Okay, so you can pass the data to second screen to third screen and instead pop the third screen you can use this to pass data to first screen. Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
                                          context,
                                          MaterialPageRoute(
                                              builder: (context) =>FirstScreen()
                                          ),
                                          ModalRoute.withName("/FirstScreen")
                                      );

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you read the docs about [state management in Flutter](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple).
I've found the `Provider` pattern especially helpful for this.